# is there an elegant way to import a js lib outside of the systemjs baseUrl setting?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

Is there an elegant way to import a js lib outside of the SystemJS baseUrl setting?

I currently have a js dir structure in my app as 'js/app/reports/' has all of the js libs used for my reports. However, I have a new requirement to import a js file from the app dir 1 level up.

Is there an elegant way to do this in SystemJS? When using the following approach, SystemJS still looks for mylib1 in the original baseURL path as opposed to looking for the js file 1 level up in the app dir:

```
SystemJS.config({ baseURL: '../js/app/reports' })
    .then(function () {
        return SystemJS.import('../app/mylib1.js');
    }).then(function () {
        return SystemJS.import('mylib2.js');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like this works:

```js
// ...
.then(function () {
    return SystemJS.import('../../js/app/Constants.js');
})
```